# Azure Function App - timmer trigger on two specific dates

Tags: cron, azure-functions

We need to send emails two times a year (1/3 and 1/9) every year. Is it possible to make a cron expression for that or do I need to make two functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! I think that would be `0 0 0 1 3,9 *`

I use this website to try expressions: https://cronexpressiondescriptor.azurewebsites.net/

The cron library Azure Functions is using: https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab

Comment: But isent this just two times a week every week?

Comment: The expression should result in a function execution on the first day of the month in May and September. So twice a year.